# Write file async node.js , understand why is not working

Tags: node.js

I have this function and is working fine:

```
        const playlistPath = path.join(config.PLAYLIST_PATH, this.playlist.id + '.json')
        let playlistString = JSON.stringify(this.playlist)

        mkdirp(config.PLAYLIST_PATH, function (_) {
            fs.writeFile(playlistPath, playlistString, function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log('error saving album to playlist %s: %o', playlistPath, err)
                console.log('The album has been added to the playlist');
            })
        })
```

But if I want to delete the var `playlistString` and use the `JSON.stringify` directly in is not working, the file is written with an undefined.

```
        const playlistPath = path.join(config.PLAYLIST_PATH, this.playlist.id + '.json')

        mkdirp(config.PLAYLIST_PATH, function (_) {
            fs.writeFile(playlistPath, JSON.stringify(this.playlist), function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log('error saving album to playlist %s: %o', playlistPath, err)
                console.log('The album has been added to the playlist');
            })
        })
```

why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the **scoping** of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). In the second code block when you write `this.playlist`, it refers to the calling function. In this case, it's your callback `function (err)...` who holds `this`.

To solve the problem assign `this` to a variable, then use that variable to refer to the **context** you want.

```
const playlistPath = path.join(config.PLAYLIST_PATH, this.playlist.id + '.json');

// Hold the value of "this" in a variable "ref"
const ref = this;

mkdirp(config.PLAYLIST_PATH, function (_) {
    fs.writeFile(playlistPath, JSON.stringify(ref.playlist), function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log('error saving album to playlist %s: %o', playlistPath, err)
        console.log('The album has been added to the playlist');
    })
})
```

Comment: Yes is that, thanks for the answer, anyway ill use the first solution to avoid use `this` out of the scope.

Comment: yes, that's what I would do too. Much cleaner to leave `this` as clean as possible